# Cleaning up Orphan Entries in core_config_data

Tags: magento2, magento-1, migration, core-config-data

Let's say I have a Magento 2 system that was migrated from Magento 1.

The folks who migrated this system ported over *everything* in the `core_config_data` table.  This includes configuration paths that don't exist in Magento 2, as well as configuration paths from extensions that are no longer installed on the system.

Are there tools for automating cleanup of this old data? If not, are there known techniques or workflows for cleaning up this old data?

Are there known bad effects for leaving these unused data fields in the `core_config_data` table? (other than future confusion for folks looking at this data)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does cause issues. For example, I had cron instances and old extension references which gave me some headaches before I realised ALL the data came over to this table. 9 months on, I still don't have a 100% stable M2 instance and put it down to not cleaning core_config_data fully and not knowing exactly what is safe to remove.